# How to make a <tr> element in vuejs that contains <slot> with html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I would like to make a table row component that can contain a slot which has html in it. The problem is that the browser hoists the text out of the table before vuejs has a chance to render it.

For example, I'd like to make a table like this https://codepen.io/mankowitz/pen/LqLRWr

```css
td, th {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.main-table {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="main-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Collapsed row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>text</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
              <th>embedded table header</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>embedded table text</td>
            </tr>            
        </table>
      </td>
      <td> Col2 </td>
      <td> Col3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        regular row col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
      <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, when I put it in a vue template, the formatting is all wrong. See https://codepen.io/mankowitz/pen/PVmBxV

```js
Vue.component("table-row", {
  props: ["collapsed"],
  template: `
<tr>
  <td v-if="collapsed" colspan="3">collapsed row</td>
  <td v-if="!collapsed"> <slot /> </td>
  <td v-if="!collapsed">  col2 </td>
  <td v-if="!collapsed">  col3 </td>
</tr>
`
});

const example = {};
const app = new Vue(example);
app.$mount("#app");
```

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1px;
}

.main-table {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table class="main-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Main Col 1</th>
        <th>Main Col 2</th>
        <th>Main Col 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

      <!-- This row has table inside table -->
      <table-row :collapsed="1">
        <p>title text</p>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>embedded table header</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>embedded table text</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </table-row>

      <!-- This row is normal  -->
      <table-row :collapsed="0">
        This row is not collapsed
      </table-row>

      <!-- This row is collapsed (hidden)  -->
      <table-row :collapsed="1">
        This row is collapsed
      </table-row>

    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're trying to do. Update your question and add the slot at the appropriate place.

Comment: I am trying to create a single table, where the <th> headers line up with each of the rows as shown in the first plain-html example. However, I'm trying to do this using a component in vuejs which makes a <tr> for each item, optionally collapsed into a single <td>. 

If the row is collapsed, I want the component to return a 3-column <td> which says collapsed. If it is NOT collapsed, I want it to put the slot in the first column and other text in columns 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with the vue render function, you can probably do it with the template, but it will be longer:

```js
Vue.component("table-row", {
  props: ["collapsed"],
  render: function(h) {
    if (this.collapsed == 1) {
      return h('tr', [h('td', {attrs: {colspan: 3}}, 'collapsed')]);
    }
    return h('tr', this.$slots.default);
  }
});


const app = new Vue({el: '#app'});
```

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1px;
}

.main-table {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table class="main-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Main Col 1</th>
        <th>Main Col 2</th>
        <th>Main Col 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

      <!-- This row has table inside table -->
      <tr is="table-row" :collapsed="0">
        <td>
        <p>title text</p>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>embedded table header</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>embedded table text</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

      <!-- This row is normal  -->
      <tr is="table-row" :collapsed="0">
        <td>This row is not collapsed</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

      <!-- This row is collapsed (hidden)  -->
      <tr is="table-row" :collapsed="1">
        <td>This row is collapsed</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

Note that if you use the slot as per my example you'll still have to include the `<td>` nodes.